# How can I get the "dir" and "copy" commands to operate on "*.xyz" but not "*.xyz~"?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

When I use `copy *.txt somefolder\` the system seems to copy all `*.txt~` files too, which is not what I want.  A similar same effect can be seen with `dir`:

```
C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Programs\Proffy>dir *.txt
 Volume in drive C is Vista
 Volume Serial Number is EC23-AD6B

 Directory of C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Programs\Proffy

29/11/2008  13:54            35,821 COPYING.txt
31/10/2009  21:54             1,644 INSTRUCTIONS.txt
06/06/2009  15:57             1,393 INSTRUCTIONS.txt~
04/01/2009  11:59               116 Notes.txt
19/04/2009  16:53               134 README.txt
04/01/2009  12:42               132 README.txt~
31/10/2009  21:30               197 TODO.txt
31/10/2009  19:10               414 TODO.txt~
               8 File(s)         39,851 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  41,938,862,080 bytes free

C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Programs\Proffy>
```

How can I get `dir` and `copy` to only operate on files that end with `.txt` and not `.txt~`?

Comment: When I first saw this question, I thought 'yes, that's useful and clear' so I upvoted it. Then I started adding an answer which was coming to the conclusion 'they're treated as special to remind you to rename or delete them'. While I was editing, someone downvoted me, with no comment to explain why. This leaves a nasty taste in my mouth, but I got the message 'help not wanted'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to execute `del *.xyz~` prior to my `copy *.xyz`.  Not brilliant, but it works.

Comment: +1. D'oh! Doing things in the right order trumps knowing all the cool commands others offered.

Comment: Well, initially I don't assume people would be willing to throw away files :-)

Comment: This is not a proper answer to your own question, sorry.  Brute force file deletion is NOT a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the shell considers both the short *and* the long name for wildcard expansion. Longer explanation can be found in [shf301's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/63777/how-can-i-get-the-dir-and-copy-commands-to-operate-on-xyz-but-not-xyz/63842#63842). This is unfortunate and probably a left-over from Ye Olde Days of DOS because that's what `cmd` is trying to be compatible with—sort of—after all.

Several options here:

1. Use `forfiles`, which has a different semantic for wildcard expansion:

   ```
   forfiles /m *.txt /c "cmd /c copy @file foo"
   ```

   This is available at least on Vista and later.
2. Use `for` and check the extension:

   ```
   for %a in (*.txt) do @if %~xa==.txt @copy "%i" foo
   ```

   Unfortunately `for` also returns any files with the `.txt~` extension when only using wildcard expansion. That's why we need to check the extension a second time.
3. Use `xcopy`. While `xcopy` has the same semantics for wildcard expansion as the shell you can give it a file with names to ignore:

   ```
   echo .txt~>tmpfile
   xcopy *.txt foo /exclude:tmpfile
   del tmpfile
   ```
4. Use `robocopy`. While `robocopy` has the same semantics for wildcard expansion as the shell you can give it a list of files/wildcards to ignore:

   ```
   robocopy . foo *.txt /XF *.txt~
   ```
5. Use `for`, `dir` and `findstr` in an appropriate combination. This essentially just filters out all lines that have a `~` at the end and operates on the rest. The `if` variant above was more elegant, I think.

   ```
   for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (`dir /b *.txt ^| findstr /r "[^~]$"`) do @copy "%i" foo
   ```
6. Just for completeness: PowerShell:

   ```
   Copy-Item *.txt foo
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to stop `dir`/`copy` from matching only `*.txt` but I can explain why `*.txt` returns what it does; it matches the short file name which ends with .txt for all the files, do a `dir /x *.txt` to see this.  This problem occurs for every set of extensions that start with the same first three characters (e.g. `*.htm` will match htm, html, and even htmlasdfasdf).

Also most every Windows application will act this way because the API the OS provides to search for files [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) matches the long file names and short files names. To quote:

> The search includes the long and short file names.

You'll have to do some sort of custom filtering as Johannes Rössel answer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Since Joey mentioned completeness, I note, as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/238900/winxp-dir-command-3-and-4-char-extensions-are-the-same/248976#248976), that this varies according to what command interpreter's `DIR` and `COPY` commands one uses.  The [`DIR` command in Take Command](http://jpsoft.com./help/dir.htm) and [its `COPY` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/copy.htm), for examples,  [only match long names by default](http://jpsoft.com./help/lfnsearch.htm) and so don't exhibit this behaviour. ([Matching of short as well as long names can be turned on](http://jpsoft.com./help/index.htm?wildcards.htm#sfn) for compatibility with CMD's `DIR` and `COPY` commands.)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer cover copying files just fell, but not listing them.

You can use the [archive bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit) for both purposes. Although it's intended to be used with [XCOPY](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)<sup>1</sup>, it also works with [DIR](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)<sup>2</sup>.

Steps:

1. Make sure the archive bit is set for all `.txt` files:

   ```
    ATTRIB +A *.txt
   ```
2. Remove the archive bit from all `.txt~` files:

   ```
    ATTRIB +A *.txt~
   ```
3. List all `.txt` files which have their archive bit set:

   ```
    DIR /AA *.txt
   ```

   or copy them to `somefolder`:

   ```
    XCOPY /A *.txt somefolder/
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup> XCOPY uses the `/A` switch to exclude all files which do not have their archive bit set. This can be used to exclude certain files (e.g., temporary files) from daily backups. With the `/M` switch, it also removes the archive bit from the files, which is handy when copying files to small storage devices (e.g., diskettes). Also, modifying a files automatically sets the archive bit, so the `/M` switch can be used for incremental backups.

<sup>2</sup> `DIR /AA` shows only files which have their archive attribute set.

Answer (score -1):

you could try:
copy "*.txt"

Comment: That's *exactly* the same as without the quotes. So what should this accomplish?

Comment: It seems like it would disinclude the '~' suffix. Hence me using the phrase "could try."